# How can I print out newPassArray[i] as String in few lines in Java by NOT USING Stream?

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

Dear people who can solve this question, I truly appreciate your kindness!
I am a new programming learner(less than 1 year)

I try to use toSting() but it will print out the empty index too, how can i get rid off those empty index and just show the scores I want by NOT using Stream
Here's my code:

```
public class ArrayStream4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] scores = {100, 50, 40, 70, 90};
        // Question: Please calculate the following: How many individuals have achieved a "passing" grade(i>=60) and print out the grade? The total score? The average? The highest score? The lowest score?
        
        int total = 0; 
        int max = scores[0];
        int min = scores[0];
        int passCount = 0;
        int [] newPassArray = new int[scores.length];
        int passingIndex = 0;


        for(int score : scores){
            total += score;
            
            if(score > max){
                max = score;
            }
            if (score < min){
                min = score;
            }
            if(score >= 60){
                passCount ++;
                newPassArray[passingIndex] = score;
                passingIndex ++;
            }
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < passingIndex; i++) {
                System.out.print(newPassArray[i]);
                
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("PASS grade: " + Arrays.toString(newPassArray));
            System.out.printf("Total grade: %d\n", total);
            System.out.printf("Min grade: %d\n", min);
            System.out.printf("Max grade: %d\n", max);
            System.out.printf("PASSCount: %d\n", passCount);

    }
}
```

Comment: ->[100, 70, 90, 0, 0]
-------------------------
I want:
->[100, 70, 90]

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!!

```
public class ArrayStream4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] scores = {100, 50, 40, 70, 90};
        int total = 0;
        int max = scores[0];
        int min = scores[0];
        int passCount = 0;
        List<Integer> newPassList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int score : scores) {
            total += score;

            if (score > max) {
                max = score;
            }
            if (score < min) {
                min = score;
            }
            if (score >= 60) {
                newPassList.add(score);
                passCount++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("PassGrade: " + newPassList);
        System.out.printf("SumGrade: %d\n", total);
        System.out.printf("MINGrade: %d\n", min);
        System.out.printf("MAXGrade: %d\n", max);
        System.out.printf("PassCount: %d\n", passCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy a new array and print.

```
System.out.println("PASS grade: " + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(newPassArray, passingIndex)));
```